# Python: What is the function player[key] = value doing in this block of code?

Tags: python

```
def basketball_player(first, last, **player_info):
    player = {}
    player['first name'] = first
    player['last name'] = last
    for key, value in player_info.items():
        player[key] = value
    return player
player_profile = basketball_player('lebron', 'james',
                                   team = 'cavaliers',
                                   number = '23')
print(player_profile)
```

I understand everything else, i just dont quite get why you assign value to play[key]

Comment: Because it is populating the `player` dict with the optional keyword arguments.

Comment: The loop assigns key-value pairs from `player_info` to `key` and `value`, and then the `key` is used as a key in `player` to store `value`. It's a verbose, manual way of doing what `player.update(player_info)` would do, copy the key-value pairs over.

Comment: For your Lebron James example, those key-value pairs are `'team'`, `'cavaliers'` and `'number'`, `'23'`

Comment: `def basketball_player(first, last, **player_info): return {'first_name': first, 'last_name': last, **player_info}` would be a more concise way of spelling the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key to your answer is knowing and understanding what `**player_info` is doing and what the `.items()` method is doing.

The `**` spread operator (as you may already know) allows you to pass an arbitrary number of keyword arguments into a method. So, essentially, when you do:

```
player_profile = basketball_player('lebron', 'james',
                                   team = 'cavaliers',
                                   number = '23')
```

You have assigned the following values to your variables:

```
first = 'lebron'
last = 'james'
player_info = {'team': 'cavaliers', 'number': '23'}
```

`player_info` is a `dict`.

On any `dict` in python, you can call the `items()` method to turn it into a list of tuples in the form of `[(<KEY>, <VALUE>)]`.

So, in your instance, `player_info.items()` becomes:

```
[('team', 'cavaliers'), ('number', '23')]
```

When you do your `for` loop, it is looping through the list of tuples. And, for each tuple, it is assigning `[0]` to the `key` variable and `[1]` to the `value`.

Therefore, when you call `player[key]` on the first iteration through the `player_info.items()` list, they `key` is the same as `player_info.items()[0]` or ... in this case `'team'`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the thorough answer. Much appreciated!